# How to structure dask to stream to random forrest classifier

Tags: classification, h5py, dask

I have a number of h5py datasets in 1 file where the class label is the dataset name and the shape is `(20000,250000`)  of `float64` compressed using `gzip`

How would the community suggest I use dask to enable random forrest training without needing to load entire datasets into memory?

Im working with a high core, high memory instance.

I should have mentioned I have 3 class labels.

**Update**:
My current thinking of loading the data was to create a dask array for each class label with the shape of `(20000,250000)` then concatenate the 3 arrays together. If I did that would I be able to use the distributed random forrest mentioned in the comments to then create the smaller training and test data frames needed?

Comment: Which random forest implementation are you intending to use?

Comment: scikit-learn but if you think there is a better alternative I'd look at that too

Comment: You might look at http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2016/04/20/dask-distributed-part-5

Comment: That does look interesting, any recommendations for working the data from h5py to a state I could break down to datasets to train multiple classifiers on?